# Error: ValueError: time data 'N/A' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d' - Python

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services

I am a junior in DevOps and I need to create a code that returns some results from spreadsheet, therefore I have updated this code that I found from internet.

The result:

[Result code without error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPizy.png)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from sys import stdin
import datetime
import json
import base64
from datetime import date, timedelta

dt = date.today()

report = json.loads(stdin.read())
table = base64.b64decode(report["Content"]).splitlines()
head = table[0].split(",")
table = table[1:]

for row in iter(table):
    user = dict(zip(head, row.split(",")))
    print ("\033[1m  USER: \033[0m \t  %s \033[1m  MFA_ACTIVE: \033[0m  %s  \033[1m PASSWORD ENABLED: \033[0m  %s  \033[1m  KEY ROTATED: \033[0m %s \n") % (user["user"], user["mfa_active"], user["password_enabled"], ((dt-(datetime.datetime.strptime((user["access_key_1_last_rotated"]).split('T')[0],"%Y-%m-%d").date()))))
```

My issue is, when I have a data like *N/A* for *access_key_1_last_rotated*, it returns a error:

*ValueError: time data 'N/A' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'*

How can I customize the code to ignore a data like *N/A*?

Comment: Can you not just use `try/except` to convert to `datetime` prior to the `print` line?

Comment: Also, what do you mean "ignore data"? As in, if it has an "N/A" value, nothing should be printed at all?

Comment: Thanks @roganjosh. In my spreadsheet I have the data in format like 02/02/2016 where in this part '((dt-(datetime.datetime.strptime((user["access_key_1_last_rotated"]).split('T')[0],"%Y-%m-%d").date())))) ' I need to find the difference between today until 02/02/2016, but sometimes I do not have the date 02/02/2016, and yes N/A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, I'd move

```
((dt-(datetime.datetime.strptime((user["access_key_1_last_rotated"]).split('T')[0],"%Y-%m-%d").date()))))
```

out of the print statement and assign it to a variable.  Then, quick and dirty, you can wrap in a try-except

```
var my_date = "N/A"
try:
    my_date = ((dt-(datetime.datetime.strptime((user["access_key_1_last_rotated"]).split('T')[0],"%Y-%m-%d").date()))))
except ValueError as v:
    # print v somewhere
    # print(v)
    # or just pass
    pass
print ("\033[1m  USER: \033[0m \t  %s \033[1m  MFA_ACTIVE: \033[0m  %s  \033[1m PASSWORD ENABLED: \033[0m  %s  \033[1m  KEY ROTATED: \033[0m %s \n") % (user["user"], user["mfa_active"], user["password_enabled"], my_date)
```

There's quite a lot going on in that date calculation so you may want to break it down further if dates start appearing in strange formats

Comment: Thanks @Steve Bradshaw, but as I am not so good with programming could you paste all code with the modification?

I am a Network engineer :)

Comment: Replace your print statement with the (edited) code above.

Comment: Thanks @Steve Bradshaw.

I have edited the code, but is showing just one result than all. I do not know if I could explain the question right, but I would like to show all results but the data where I have N/A, I want to show N/A in KEY ROTATED

Comment: I have edited the code and now is showing all results, but the KEY ROTATED is showing nothing.

Comment: I'd removed the user["password_enabled"] entry from the last line (the formatted print).  I've edited the last line to add it back in.